associations and cardinalities in class diagrams
I have two classes, one called Person with the attributes: name, surname, date of birth, tax code;
the second called Reward with the attributes: name, id, type.
The type attribute is an enumeration that can take on two values ​​which are: single or team.
How can I combine the fact that a person can win one of the prizes every year and that the single prize can be won every year by one person while the team prize can be won by multiple people in the same year?
I had thought about creating an association between person and prize. Put the year attribute in the association class between person and reward. However, what should I do with the cardinalities given that a single award must be won by one person every year while the team one could be won by multiple people?
I thought about creating three classes
person
trophies with two specializations which are individual and team.
and company
associations

an association that links a team trophy to a many-to-many company.
a many-to-many association between trophy and person.
Now I have a doubt, how do I guarantee that an individual trophy is won by only one person every year, while the team trophy is won by several people every year?
obviously an individual trophy can be won by more than one person, but in different years.


Hello. I am happy to see that the answer to this question helped you to progress on your problem, as you have posted a new question with a more complete model and now ask about its intersting evolutions  (player career). If this answer helped, could  you upvote it tho show other readers that it's worth reading. If it solved your initial question, i.e how to manage the association of persons with the prize, could you accept it  to show it's the solution ?

Let's start with the case of the single prize ("reward"). Indeed, the solution of putting the year in an association class could be the start of a promising solution.
However this association class does not guarantee the constraint of a single person for a prize in a year given year, since multiple person/price tuples could share the use the same value for their  year attribute. Even the {unique} adornment would not guarantee this uniqueness. You would have to add an ad-hoc constraint that is fortunately easy to implement in a database:

Another alternative would be to add a year qualifier to the Reward you could the have a multiplicity 1 on the side of the Person (meaning that for a prize an a year there is exactly one person), and keep a * multiplicity on the side of the qualifier:

Now the enumeration makes all this much more complex, as the rules depend on its value. You would have to have * multiplicities on both sides, but have to add a lot complex constraint on the association. The diagram would remain complex to read.
Another alternative could use generalization: the Prize would always be associated with a single Person, that could  be specialized (inheritance) further into PhysicalPerson (with all the attributes) and TeamPerson ( a moral person) which is itself associated with several PhysicalPersons (Team members).  This makes the rules and the model more accurate:

Alternatively, you could also use generalization to get rid of your enumeration and specialize Prize. You could even combine the two, but you'd need to balance the added complexity for your database implementation and the higher power of the OO modeling.

Thank you for your answer. I modeled the class diagram like this. person , prize specialization (total disjoint) = individual and team. time association class with year attribute. I designed a constraint in which I say that the individual prize can be won by at most one person for year. the cardinalities of the association are [0..N] and [0..N] for the team trophy I don't have to describe any constraints like for the individual right?Would the rule that a person can win more individual than team awards in the same year be respected? team rewards will definitely be associated with more people.

@dok yes, this is fine. But intuitively you feel something is missing: a team prize is for a team, but in this model you only associate several persons. Nothing guarantees that it's not persons belonging to two teams or several individuals. (by the way, in UML-speak it's "multiplicities"; cardinalities in uml is the count of one specific set of instances and the cardinality must then be in the boundaries of the multiplicities. This terminology is slightly different from entity-relationships-speak ;-) )

I understand what you mean. I add another class called team and I create a history in which period the person worked in that team. In the history class I can put information on how many days a person worked and how many projects he performed. A team, on the other hand, is denoted by name and nationality.
at this point the relationships would be
person-works-team
prize-person
team-trophyteam
Do you know if I can post a class diagram here in the comments or in trying to answer the question?
